# RewritCond. Too many internal redirects. LimitInternalRecursion.

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This code behaves different deppending the order of the conditions:

**This code works**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mypage.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !test/[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !x/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !test2/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test2/$1 [L]
```

**This one doesn´t work - Internal Server Error 550-**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mypage.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !test2/[NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !x/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !test/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test2/$1 [L]
```

**Server log:**

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

How it comes to that loop? and why only in one of the cases?

Comment: What are you typing in as a URL when that happens?

Comment: Internal sever error  (500).
Looks like a loop of redirection, that I don't reach to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a hard to notice typing mistake. There is no space between the final parameters in one of the conds.

It is easier to spot here:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !foo/[NC]`  <-fails 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !foo/ [NC]`  <-works